# Ошибка при линковке Excel с SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, компоновщик

Ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

```
Поставщик OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" для связанного сервера "XlsLnkSrv" вернул сообщение "Не удается запустить приложение. Системная база данных отсутствует или открыта с монопольным доступом другим пользователем.".

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Поставщик OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" для связанного сервера "XlsLnkSrv" сообщил об ошибке. Ошибка проверки подлинности.

Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Не удалось проинициализировать объект источника данных поставщика OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" для связанного сервера "XlsLnkSrv".
```

Сперва сделал запрос на создание связывающего сервера:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'XlsLnkSrv', 
@srvproduct = 'ACE 12.0', 
@provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
@datasrc = 'C:\Путь\Номерная база.xlsx', 
@provstr = 'Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes'
```

Затем сделал запрос на выборку и здесь возникло исключение:

```
select * from openquery (XlsLnkSrv, 'Select * from [Лист1$]')
```

Версия пакета офис у меня 2021 года. В качестве провайдера использую OLE DB Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0. Excel я пробовал закрывать ничего не изменилось. Пытался выдать права в свойствах документа, также безуспешно.

Comment: Сервер то локальный?

Comment: Сервер локальный